# Business rule updater

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to increase the speed of my application at the moment. My inserting/updating methods were opening every time a new connection which took too much time. I read that it's better to create a connection object and pass it to different methods. It worked fine but I'm just curious if this is a good practice.

This is a part of my code I wrote:

```
public class BusinessRuleUpdaterDaoImplV2 extends OracleBaseDao implements BusinessRuleUpdaterDaoV2 {

    @Override
    public boolean updateBusinessRule(BusinessRule businessRule) {
        try(Connection con = super.getConnectionConfigDb()) {
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            if (updateTableBusinessRule(con,businessRule)){
                return true;
            } else {
                con.rollback();
                return false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean updateTableBusinessRule(Connection con, BusinessRule businessRule){
        String queryBr = "UPDATE BUSINESSRULE SET ERRORMESSAGE = ?, SQLCODE = ?, CUSTOMNAME = ?, OPERATOR_ID = ? WHERE BUSINESSRULE_ID = ?";
        try(PreparedStatement pstmtBr = con.prepareStatement(queryBr)) {
            pstmtBr.setString(1,businessRule.getErrorMessage());
            pstmtBr.setString(2,businessRule.getSqlQuery());
            pstmtBr.setString(3,businessRule.getName());
            pstmtBr.setInt(4,businessRule.getOperatorID());
            pstmtBr.setInt(5,businessRule.getBusinessRuleID());
            pstmtBr.executeUpdate();
            pstmtBr.close();
            return updateTableTargetTable(con,businessRule);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean updateTableTargetTable(Connection con, BusinessRule businessRule){
        String queryTt = "UPDATE TARGETTABLE SET NAME = ? WHERE TABLE_ID = ?";
        for (int i = 0 ; i < businessRule.getTableListSize() ; i++) {
            try (PreparedStatement pstmtTt = con.prepareStatement(queryTt)) {
                pstmtTt.setString(1,businessRule.getListOfTables().get(i).getName());
                pstmtTt.setInt(1, businessRule.getListOfTables().get(i).getId());
                pstmtTt.executeUpdate();
                pstmtTt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean updateTableAttribute(Connection con, BusinessRule businessRule){
        // return updateTableValue(con, businessRule)
        return false;
    }

    private boolean updateTableValue(Connection con, BusinessRule businessRule){
        //return updateTableStack(con, businessRule)
        return false;
    }

    private boolean updateTableStack(Connection con, BusinessRule businessRule){
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the first method, `updateBusinessRule()`, I'm opening a connection and passing it to the next method. If one of the methods returns false, it will make a roll back in the first method.

I'm also curious about why intellij is telling me that `pstmtTt.close()` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is ok to re-use the `Connection`.

I would not try-catch all the `SqlExceptions` in the `update*` methods. Just let them throw. Then you don't need all the `boolean` logic either. Makes it simpler I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If your application constantly/periodically makes DB queries it is logical to keep/store a DAO object as a singleton that connects to the service once (possibly on application startup). This way you are not going to lose time waiting until the connection appears every time

Answer (score -1):

You can use a connection pool like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) or [c3p0](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0); it reduces the time for new connection setup.